# ACF date field gives randomly wrong output

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, advanced-custom-fields, strtotime

I'm using this code but the output sometimes results in 01.01.70. Clearly my code is wrong. But for the life of me I don't know where. The date comes from datefield ACF called 'datum_event'.

I have 2 different ways of showing the date on the site. It loads like l j F Y on the eventpage itself (retour format set in ACF). But I need it to show d.m.y in an event calender. (not retour format set in ACF).

It works up to the point where some months show as expected (13.04.23), but other months show again as 01.01.1970. I'm lost really.

April, June, September, November, December show fine. The other months go wrong and show as 01.01.1970.

So I end up with this code:

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_field' ) ) {
    $date = get_field( 'datum_event' );
        $date_parts = explode(" ", $date, 2);
    if ( isset($date_parts[1]) && is_string( $date ) ) {
        $html .= '
' . date( 'd.m.y', strtotime( $date_parts[1] ) ) . '
    ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like strtotime simply doesn't "understand" your display format in some cases. You should not try and work with an already formatted value at this point. Try and set the third parameter of `get_field` to false, to get the unformatted value. (And then use the full thing, without any exploding.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_field' ) ) {
$date = get_field('datum_event',false,false);

if ( isset($date) && is_string( $date ) ) {
    $html .= '' . date( 'd.m.y', strtotime( $date) ) . '
';
}
```

This is the solution!